# Tags [mht] and [mhtml]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Noticed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102712/how-to-create-mhtml-standalone-file-with-same-page-links), why do we have two tags for the same thing?

Merge/synonymise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag [mht](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mht) merged and synonymized with [mhtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mhtml).